# Cohomology groups $Coker(i_{n-1}^*)$ depends on only $H_{n-1}(C)$ and $G$. Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

On page 193 of Hatcher at the bottom. He says

> $$0 \to B_{n-1} \to Z_{n-1} \to H_{n-1}(C) \to 0 (vi)$$
>
> Note that the group  $Coker(i_{n-1}^*)$  that we are interested in is
>   $H^1(F;G)$ where $F$ is the free resolution in (vi). **Part (b) of the following lemma therefore
>   shows that $Coker i∗_{n−1}$ depends only on $H_{n−1}(C)$ and $G$.**
>
> [image]

Which two resolution is he using to derive this result?

Is it $(iv)$ and $(v)$?? Very confused.

How does he pass through $H^n(C;G)$?

Answer (score 1):

*Math*: the claim is that if we change the chain complex $C$ and pick a totally different complex C', requiring only that it have the same homology in the $n-1$ spot, then the complex $\text{Hom}(C, G)$ and the complex $\text{Hom}(C', G)$ would still have the same $\text{cok}(\iota^*_{n-1})$ (up to canonical isomorphism). The claim is attained by taking the sequence (vi) and the analogous sequence (vi') for $C'$ and applying part two of the lemma.

*Philosophy*: if this is too much arrow-ception you might try skipping these two pages and just reading the statement of the universal coefficient theorem and doing a couple exercises, then coming back to it. It's one of those theorems that you kind of have to prove for yourself instead of following someone else's proof because it's 8 million steps in a row, any individual one of which isn't too bad, but all of which together are confusing the first 7 to 12 times.

Comment: No I know what the lemma is saying. I am asking which specific sequence they are talking about. If you are taking (vi), what is the (vi')? This doesn't exist, it is artificial.

Comment: (vi') is (vi) but for $C'$ instead of $C$. That is what it means to say that the cokernel doesn't depend on the complex but only the homology.

Comment: So you are telling me we are putting the same sequence by itself and all the vertical maps are identity...?

Comment: @Hawk I am saying we are taking two different resolutions of $H_{n-1}(C)$. the vertical maps aren't the identity (except the third vertical map, which is).

Comment: $0 \to B_{n-1} \to Z_{n-1} \to H_{n-1}(C) \to 0 $ and this mysterious notational $0 \to B_{n-1}' \to Z_{n-1}' \to H_{n-1}(C') \to 0 $ row by row...? How do we know $C \to C'$ is an isomorphism (or I guess identity) in the first place? This only shows $Hom(H(C),G) \leftrightarrow H^1(C;G) \approx H^1(C',G) = coker(i_{n-1}')$?

Comment: @Hawk Remember, $H_{n-1}(C) = H_{n-1}(C')$ by assumption, so we get that arrow. We definitely do not have an arrow $C \to C'$. We have an arrow from (vi) to (vi') which is essentially unique by Lemma (ii) in that it induces an isomorphism after applying Hom into G and computing homology, and therefore the cokernel of $i'$ does not depend on the choice of complex $C$ but only on its homology in degree $n-1$.

Comment: When did we impose the condition $H(C) = H(C')$?

Comment: @Hawk remember, only in degree $n-1$. See the first sentence of the answer. Again, this is what Hatcher means when he says "only depends on $H_{n-1}(C)$."He means if we pick a differnt complex, we compute an isomorphic thing for that particular cokernel, provided the different complex has the same $H_{n-1}$.

Comment: Well it is in your answer, but when he did claim that? He didn't seem like he used this in his book.

Comment: @Hawk when we say "this construction [which seems to depend on $X$ and $Y$] only depends on $X$ and $f(Y)$"what we mean is "if you replace $Y$ with some $Y'$ such that $f(Y)$ and $f(Y')$ are the same, then this construction doesn't change." So in this case, Hatcher says the cokernel of $\iota_{n-1}^*$ only depends on $H_{n-1}(C)$ so we have to pick a different $C'$ with the same $H_{n-1}$ and see that we'd compute the same thing. We do that by resolving $H_{n-1}(C) $ in two different ways (vi) and (vi'), applying $Hom(*, G)$, computing first homology, and applying step ii of the lemma.

Comment: So I think I know what is going on now (Correct me if I am wrong). Basically they fixed $H$ in the lemma, which is your assumption that the homology groups are assumed to be the same. This shows that the cohomology depends on $H$ and that the rest of the resolution do not matter. Hence this means that the cohomology is *invariant* under the free resolution of $H$. A trivial question now is, what about $G$? This should be super obvious, but how does it show the dependence on $G$?